# Change the Home Page in Chrome browser from Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Does anyone know how to change the user's Home page in Chrome Browser from Chrome Extension?
I tried some solutions like `document.setHomePage` but it doesn't work.

In firefox, I am using the following code:

```
prefs.setCharPref('browser.startup.homepage', searchUrl);
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The closest thing currently available is allowing your extension to [override the "new tab" page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/override.html).  include this in your manifest:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...

  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "myPage.html"
  },
  ...
}
```

However, your users may set their new tab page to any other url as their home page.

Answer (score 2):

It is now possible to override the homepage through the [`chrome_settings_overrides`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/settings_override) option:

```js
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "chrome_settings_overrides": {
    "homepage": "http://www.homepage.com",
  }
}
```

Comment: possible to use an html file inside the extension?

Comment: @datdinhquoc [MDN state that it is possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/chrome_settings_overrides#Syntax): "The replacement is given as a URL. The URL may point to a file bundled with the extension, in which case it is given as a URL relative to the manifest.json file."

Comment: works with http/https protocols, but doesn't work for me why i set "homepage" to a html file in side extension. Error: Empty dictionary for 'chrome_settings_overrides'.
Could not load manifest.

Comment: You need “chrome_url_overrides” for html.